# assemble: Access global variables in {{parseJSON}}

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

Let's say you have a partial of some sort, which uses a global variable:

```
<a href="/" class="logo"><img src="{{assets}}/logo.png"></a>
```

Once you include the partial with specific data, either `{{parseJSON}}` or external JSON data:

```
{{#parseJSON '{"demo": true}'}}
{{>navigation}}
{{/parseJSON}}
```

all global variables like `{{assets}}` "killed" or at least overridden. Is there any chance to have still access?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about `{{this.assets}}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a known "issue" with Handlebar's partials in that the context inside a partial only includes the passed in context and no parent context, etc..  you can read more about the issue [here](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/pull/182).

fortunately the Assemble team provides a [`{{partial}}` helper](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helper-partial) that will allow access to a more "expected" context, including global properties.  once this helper is installed, you use it in a slightly different way than a normal partial:

```
{{#parseJSON '{"demo": true}'}}
  {{partial "navigation"}}
{{/parseJSON}}
```

note that the `partial` helper is invoked with the name of the partial to include as a string.

that all being said, a new version of Handlebars was just released (v2.0.0-alpha.1) that may provide support for this natively.  check out the more recent posts of issue thread i linked to above.

hope this helps.

Comment: As @waynedpj said, there will be a way to access the root directly by using `@root.assets` so you should be able to use that inside your navigation partial. I don't think it's been released in a stable version of Handlebars yet, but we'll try to upgrade as quickly as possible when it is released.

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround, the other way to cope with this is to pass the parent context explicitly to the partial:

```
{{#..}}
  {{>partial}}
{{/..}}
```

Yeah.